# How to fix lack of sound Kali Linux recent install

Tags: kali-linux

I just installed the following version of Kali Linux

```
uname -a
Linux kali 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
cat /etc/issue
Kali GNU/Linux Rolling \n \l
```

And I see no speaker icon on the top tool bar. After a quick on line search, I tried to get to admin panel by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-right click of the tool bar. For some reason did not work for me. I tried the different probable key combinations like the Windows Key - <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>shift</kbd>. No luck. 
I also looked into installing ALSA, but apt-get can not find the package. Also ALSA's site said something about not downloading the binary for compile any more as it is integrated into the Kali image. I took that to mean I should have ALSA with the original install. I then found the all setting panel, and see that I do not have any audio devices listed. I have googled for linux drivers for my audio hardware, but I did not find anything. I am also not sure if I can use any driver. I see Kali is just dabian distro. Can you help resolve the issue or get me closer to a fix? What am I missing?

```
lspci -vnn | grep -iA 10 audio
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [8086:3b56] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [103c:3659]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at db100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0be3] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company High Definition Audio Controller [103c:3659]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] [8086:0084]
    DeviceName: Intel(R) Wi-Fi Link 1000
```

Comment: I think there is no error. Both of your cards are controlled by `snd_hda_intel`. Look at your pulseaudio settings. (and don't use kali as primary desktop)

Comment: Mint or Fedora would be good starting Linuxes.